# Automatic registration, requiring no user input

Tags: android, authentication

How do some popular apps require no user registration, so the registration is automatic and requires no user input yet they still manage to track users.

My biggest questions about this is, how are they authenticating with the server, I assume a token after registration is being stored on the device and all other requests will use that token.

Now say the user changes devices or uninstalls his the app then reinstalls it, how does the server know which user that is, does it use the telephone number from the device to authenticate?

Suggestions on how I could accomplish this would be great.

Thanks!